# C++: Looking for correction for "returning address of local variable..."

Tags: c++

I am, currently, taking an online C++ class to fill my time while unemployed and I have a question concerning returning the address of a local variable. I realize that this is not a recommended practice and I'm looking for an alternate solution to what I'm trying to do (return data for copying into my object "co" which is a class Coord object). BTW ... the program works as far as results goes.  But it does get the warning C4172  "returning address of local variable or temporary...".  Can you help me out here?

HERE ARE THE DETAILS: In my homework program I have a function that returns the address of local variable Coord co (Coord is my constructed class with two int fields ... obviously ... coordinates).  My goal was to use the Coord copy constructor to copy the data using the address of that local variable.

//The calling program declares object co of class Coord as follows

```
Coord co;
```

//calling program can makes the call to function requestMove() in a couple of places.
//here is one of the calls

```
co = bd.requestMove(pHuman);
```

//The signature of requestMove() is

```
const Coord& requestMove(Player&);
```

//The called function, requestMove(), has a local Coord object nodeAddress and it populates nodeAddress. The return statement is:

```
return nodeAddress;
```

Comments and suggestions would be welcome.  Thanks, much.

Comment: Returning a reference to a local variable is simply not allowed. Why not return the `Coord` by copy? So the signature would be `Coord requestMove(Player&);`

Comment: return it by value, and RVO will makes it as efficient as a return by reference

Comment: I'm just learning how to use Stack Overflow ... so I'll just type here and let you know that I'm taking it all in (all of your answers) and will get to working on the solution/update later on today.  Thanks, so much for responding so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a reference to a temporary duration object, but this is just one of the ways to shoot oneself into the foot. C++ is not a nanny language and allows this.

Consider:

```
foo& bar() {
    foo f;
    return f;
}
```

This code will compile, but what happens? At first you create an object `f`, but when you return from `bar`, the object `f` goes out of scope and is destructed (this is the essence of RAII). The returned reference will be a 'wild reference' to the object that no longer exists, and trying to access that memory location is simply undefined behaviour (which is a nice way of saying that what the program will do -- nobody knows. For all intents and purposes it can crash, it can eat your cat or boil you coffee).

The compiler simply warns you that the code won't probably do what you expect it to do.

The correction would be to return the object by value here.

```
foo bar() {
    foo f;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly and for the details response.  I'll be looking into this a bit later and will get back to here to update all.  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

the object will be destroyed after the scope exits, so it's memory is unallocated, and having an object pointing to that memory means it's undefined behavior. The most optimal solution would be to change the return statement to `return Coord{args...};` and change the function signature to `Coord requestMove(Player&);` it will take advantage of guaranteed [copy ellision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) meaning that `auto co = bd.requestMove(pHuman);` will result to `auto co = Coord{args...};`

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I'll look into your suggestion (and all of the others) a bit later today and will get back to Stack Overflow with my update.  Thanks, again.